# Centering a String against another string

Tags: c#

I would like to center a string against another string by making sure the second string displayed appears centered to the first string output. How do I go about doing this in C# please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this console output, WPF, or what?

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.NET, Console or Web Forms?

Comment: Also, I don't believe this is possible. If the first string was

    short

and the second is 

    something significantly longer

It's not possible to center it, because the first string is the one that needs to be changed.

Comment: You have gotten some good answers for various kinds of output, but the question is unclear and not really useful. It would be good to react to the input and clarify what you need centered; characters or pixels..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear (examples help clarify). Further, you haven't fully specified the output that your expecting (do we throw when the second string can't be centered on the first string because it's too long?) You'll find that fully [specifying your requirements](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html) will help you write your code! That said, I think you're looking for something like that following.

Use

```
 public static string CenterWithRespectTo(string s, string against) {
     if(s == null) {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
     }
     if(against == null) {
         throw new AgrumentNullException("against");
     }
     if (s.Length > against.Length) {
         throw new InvalidOperationException();
     }
     int halfSpace = (against.Length - s.Length) / 2;
     return s.PadLeft(halfSpace + s.Length).PadRight(against.Length);
 }
```

so that

```
string s = "Hello";
string against = "My name is Slim Shady";
Console.WriteLine(CenterWithRespectTo(s, against) + "!");
Console.WriteLine(against);
```

produces

```
        Hello        !  
My name is Slim Shady
```

(The extraneous '!' is so that you can see the padding.)

You can easily modify this so that in cases where there is an odd amount of additional space the extra space goes on the left or right (currently it goes on the right) according to your needs (refactor accepting a parameter!).

Comment: This will only work for non-proportional (fixed width) fonts.  Not in general for all fonts... If two strings were asymetrically populated with different width characters (first string has preponderence of wide chaaracters, (Ws, Ms, Hs, etc), and second string has preponderence of narrow characters like i, l, punctuation marks, etc.), then this will not work.

Comment: He said center strings, not center visual representations of strings (text). (I concur with the obvious statement that his requirements are vague and unclear.)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to just put the strings into horizontally aligned text boxes, and set the textalignment property for both of them to "centered".

Otherwise, You need to measure the pixel length of the string, when drawn in a specified font... Then offset the shorter string's start x-coordinate by half the difference between the two lengths...

```
string s1 = "MyFirstString";
string s2 = "Another different string";
Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 12f);
Font f2 = new Font("Times New Roman", 14f);
Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
SizeF sizeString1 = g.MeasureString(s1, f1),
      sizeString2 = g.MeasureString(s2, f2);
float offset = sizeString2.Width - sizeString1.Width / 2;
// Then offset (to the Left) the position of the label 
// containing the second string by this offset value...
// offset to the left, because If the second string is longer,  
// offset will be positive.
Label lbl1 = // Label control for string 1,
      lbl2 = // Label control for string 2;
lbl1.Text = s1; 
lbl1.Font = f1;
lbl1.Left = //Some value;
lbl2.Text = s2; 
lbl2.Font = f2;
lbl2.Left == lbl1.Left - offset;
```

Comment: This will center visual representations of string (text) in a window, but is not necessarily the problem that he was trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  Perhaps the `.PadLeft` and `.PadRight` methods would help you.